# How to generate a set of orthogonal polynomials with a special weight function?

Tags: polynomials

Regarding to $e^{-ax-bx^2}$ as the weight function , how can I generate a set of orthogonal polynomials? I just know the `Orthogonalize` command in Mathematica which seems that uses 1 as weight function by Gram-Schmidt method, other commands such as `HermiteH` and `LaguerreL` generate special polynomials. But I don't know how to do my case. In fact I try to perform the following step which is a part of one article:

> Generate a set of orthogonal polynomials with the square of the
> Ground-state wave function as the weight function (WF) adopting any of
> the standard algorithms

where Ground-state wave function is $e^{-ax-bx^2}$.

Comment: What inner product are you using for these polynomials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the $x^n$ in your $A$ it will work. The ground state wave-function $\psi(x)=\exp(-ax-bx^2)$ and the weight function is its square $\psi^2(x)=\exp(-2 a x-2 b x^2)$. It helps avoid numerical instability later on if we normalize the weight function first by doing:
$$
\hat{w}(x)=\psi^2(x)*\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^2(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)^{-1}
=\frac{\psi^2(x)\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{\frac{a^2}{2 b}}}
$$

```
(* ground state wave function *)
ψ = Exp[-a x - b x^2];

(* weight function is the square of ψ *)
w = ψ^2;

(* norm of the weight function *)
normw = Integrate[w, {x, -∞, ∞}];

(* normalized weight function *)
wnormed = w/normw;

(* orthogonalizes the monomials 1,x,x^2,x^3,...,x^n assuming an inner-product convolution with normalized weight fn *)
symbasis[n_?IntegerQ] :=
 Orthogonalize[x^# & /@ Range[0, n], 
  Integrate[wnormed * #1 * #2, {x, -∞, ∞}] &]
```

For example, you can then get a basis (in symbolic $a,b$) for $n=3$ with `symbasis[3]`. Replace $a,b$ with numerical values if necessary e.g: `symbasis[3] /. {a->0.99985, b->0.00015}`. This process of getting a symbolic basis then replacing the values is slower than numerical integration but it seems to avoid the problems with precision. With this replacement we get a basis:

```
basis = symbasis[3] /. {a->0.99985, b->0.00015}
(* results: 
{1,
 0.0244949 (3332.83 + x), 
 0.000424264 (-1.11094*10^7 + x^2 + 6665.67 (3332.83 + x)), 
 6.*10^-6 (3.7037*10^10 + x^3 - 3.33283*10^7 (3332.83 + x) + 9998.5 (-1.11094*10^7 + x^2 + 6665.67 (3332.83 + x)))
}*)
```

We can verify the basis functions are orthogonal as follows:

```
(* all six pairs of the 4 basis functions are orthogonal *)
Integrate[#[[1]]*#[[2]]*(wnormed /. {a -> 0.99985, b -> 0.00015}) , {x, -∞, ∞}] & /@ Subsets[basis, {2}]

(* result: {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.} *)
```

Comment: Dear @flinty thanks a lot for your reply. I ran it in Mathematica and I got a list with 3 elements. Namely it generated a set of orthogonal polynomials (with 3 members) just using above function as weight function? However it's hard for me to understand your code. Can you explain details of your code? Also I added the original sentences appeared in the paper.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it does. I'm afraid I don't do much physics though.

Comment: Dear @flinty Good, no matter because this is a purely mathematical step. However I want to understand the details of your code, I'm new in Mathematica. Can you tell me every line of your code what does? Thanks again.

Comment: You read the quote which I included in my question? @flinty

Comment: I have commented the code. What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: Thanks, I mean the arguments inside `Orthogonalize` command

Comment: `n_?IntegerQ, a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ` just mean that `n` is checked to be an integer, and `a,b` any numbers. Then `x^# & /@ Range[0, n]`  produces the list of monomials `1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,...,x^n`. The `Integrate` in the second argument is the inner product passed to `Orthogonalize`: given polynomials #1,#2, it's doing an integral of #1 * #2 times the weight function over -infinity to infinity.

Comment: Dear @flinty many thanks, it became completely clear. My last question: Is this a common to use $x^n$ basis and is this a standard method to generate a set of orthogonal polynomials?

Comment: @Wisdom yes, the same would work for Legendre and Hermite polynomials - only the inner product changes. It doesn't matter what the monomial 'seeds' are (1,x,x^2,x^3,...) are as long as they span the space of functions you're interested in. You could also have chosen 2,3x,-6x^2, 94x^3 - but it should still generate an orthogonal set of basis polynomials. If you have questions about the underlying linear algebra and why it works, please direct those to Mathematics S.E.

Comment: Dear @flinty Oh you're a master in every sense. I got you mean completely. Thanks again.

Comment: Dear @flinty Sorry to bother you again, Your code works well, but when I set `a`s and `b`s which I have obtained in previous steps (for example `a=0.99985` and `b=0.00015`), it returns imaginary results and orthogonality isn't satisfied. Any idea?

Comment: b is too small and a is close to 1, so the weight function is basically just `Exp[-x]`, not a bell curve shape. The energy of the wf (integral squared) is too large and the orthogonalization is numerically unstable. I forgot to mention this but you should make sure your wf integrates to 1. You can see the spike in the wf if you do `Plot[Exp[-0.99985 x - 0.00015 x^2], {x, -100, 100}]` - it shoots off to very large numbers. There doesn't appear to be an easy way to fix this, even with `SetPrecision`.

Comment: Ideally, for a good basis you want `E^(a^2/(4 b)) Sqrt[π] == Sqrt[b]` or for this to be very close to equality.

Comment: Dear @flinty Thanks a lot. Your're right. I changed the options of `Integrate` command but it didn't work. However I have obtained these `a`s and `b`s for a real physical system, so I can't change them. You think there is no way to obtain a set of orthogonal polynomials with this wf as weight function? Any suggestion?

Comment: How you reached to this condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110227/discussion-between-flinty-and-wisdom).

Comment: Integrate the wf. `NIntegrate[Exp[-0.99985 x - 0.00015 x^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`. It gives  `5.889983328950299*10^725` which is huge. An ideal inner product should really satisfy $\langle x,x\rangle = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $2$ with positive leading term.  To generate orthogonal polynomials $H_n(x)$ with respect to the inner product

$$\langle f, g \rangle \colon = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline {f(x)} g(x) e^{-p(x)}dx$$

take

$$H_n(x) = (e^{-p(x)})^{(n)} \cdot e^{p(x)}$$

or

```
h[n_, x_] := D[ Exp[- (a x + b x^2)], {x,n}] Exp[ a x + b x^2];
```

Answer (score 1):

For weight function $e^{-x^2}$, the ortho-normal polynomials are the Hermite polynomials:

```
f[n_, x_] = HermiteH[n, x] / Sqrt[2^n n! Sqrt[π]];

Table[Integrate[f[n1, x] f[n2, x] E^(-x^2), {x, -∞, ∞}],
      {n1, 0, 5}, {n2, 0, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

For weight function $e^{-a x-b x^2}$ we can shift and scale these:

```
g[n_, x_] = b^(1/4) E^(-a^2/(8 b)) f[n, x Sqrt[b] + a/(2 Sqrt[b])];

Assuming[b > 0,
  Table[Integrate[g[n1, x] g[n2, x] E^(-a x - b x^2), {x, -∞, ∞}],
        {n1, 0, 5}, {n2, 0, 5}] // MatrixForm]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

For example,

```
g[3, x] // FullSimplify
```

$$
\frac{e^{-\frac{a^2}{8 b}} (a+2 b x) \left((a+2 b x)^2-6 b\right)}{4 \sqrt{3} \sqrt[4]{\pi } b^{5/4}}
$$